# Circle in curved two dimensional space possibility to calculate with metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

How can I calculate the perimeter of a circle in a curved space that is describe by following metric:
$$ds^2 = dr^2 + R^2\sin^2(r/R)d\theta^2$$

where $R$ is the radius of the sphere.

I know how to calculate it in general, or at least I could figure out (just an integral using spherical coordinates), but I was wondering if the metric was given only to describe the space or if there is a way to calculate the perimeter of the circle USING the metric. I could not find anything specific on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A circle is a curve with fixed $r$, so an infinitesimal distance along the circle is given by
$$\mathrm ds = \sqrt{0 + R^2 \sin^2(r/R) \mathrm d\theta^2}= R\sin(r/R)\mathrm d\theta$$
The only parameter being varied as you wind around the circle is $\theta$, so the total circumference becomes simply $C = \oint \mathrm ds = 2\pi R \sin(r/R)$.

Note that for $r\ll R$, this reduces to $C\approx 2\pi r$, reflecting the fact that as long as you stay in a small neighborhood, the surface of a sphere can be well-approximated by a plane.  Obviously as $r\rightarrow R$, this approximation becomes very bad.

Comment: thank you for your answer, now it is very clear to me. But I have problems transferring the same problem to the area of a circle with the same metric. If I try to integrate over $dr*d\theta *R*sin(r/R)$ (which would be the square root of the determinant of the metric tensor, as stated in the formula 2.23 on here: https://www.mv.helsinki.fi/home/syrasane/cosmo/lect2018_02.pdf  ), I get something that would be 0 if r<<R , so nonsensical?

Comment: @wendysnow When you look at the asymptotic form of an expression in some limit, you look at the lowest **non-zero** order.  When we say $f(x)\sim g(x)$, we mean that $\lim  f(x)/g(x)=1$.  For that reason, $f(x)\sim 0$ never makes sense.  All this is to say that when you compute that integral, you end up with an expression whose lowest order term is proportional to $(r/R)^2$ (which shouldn't be surprising), and which takes a very familiar form when simplified.